# VB.NET + PowerShell

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, script, powershell

Gostaria de criar um programa em VB.NET que executasse o seguinte código em PowerShell

```
Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
```

Criei um arquivo .ps1 com este código acima e coloquei desta forma no VS:

```
Shell("powershell -noexit Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs ""C:\Users\netov\Desktop\teste.ps1""", AppWinStyle.NormalFocus, True)
```

Ele executa, chama o PS como administrador, mas da o erro de que a execução de scripts foi desabilitada neste sistema e diz para eu consultar *about_Execution_Policies*

Pesquisei e vi que se eu rodar este comando  `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` no PS ele me permite (depois de digitar 'S', para sim) executar scripts.

O problema é que eu não consigo rodar este código pelo VS. Eu tentei adicionar ele no ***teste.ps1*** e também não executa.

Alguém já passou por isso, ou tem uma outra forma para resolver? Eu só quero rodar este comando de PowerShell de uma forma simples (para usuários comuns) afim de resolver o problema do iniciar do Windows para de funcionar em alguns momentos.

Comment: Que código não consegue rodar pelo VS? Qual o problema exatamente?

Comment: Quer uma forma de rodar o comando em PS Get-AppXPackage...e estou tentando com o comando Shell("powershell ...) conforme o texto acima...Você teria alguma outra forma? O que quero é simples, a execução nem tanto.

Answer (score -3):

Existe um parâmetro para o executável "powershell.exe"

-ExecutionPolicy bypass